# Is there any regular expression engine that works with multiple programming languages?

Tags: regex

Since each programming language appears to use a different syntax for regular expressions, I'm looking for a regular expression engine that is compatible with all programming languages (instead of just one or two of them). Is there any regular expression engine that works with multiple programming languages? If not, would it be feasible to create such a regex engine?

Comment: PCRE is used in many languages.

Comment: The syntax between different regular expressions is usually *mostly* consistent.  Is there a particular corner case you're running into?

Comment: I'm mainly asking this question because I'm currently trying to port some JavaScript libraries into Python and Java, and I think it would be very tedious to manually translate each JavaScript regular expression into a JavaScript or Python regular expression. I wish that there were some kind of language-independent standard for regular expression syntax.

Comment: @CarlNorum, true, unless you're using emacs.

Comment: Or sed. Or MySQL (it doesn't have escape sequences like \d and \w).

Comment: What does it mean for an engine to be "compatible with" a programming language? Either it uses that engine or it doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar I mean a regular expression library that is implemented in multiple languages - so that it can be used in each of these languages.

Comment: And how does that solve your problem? If you're porting into Python and Java, what difference does it make if Perl's RE library would be more compatible? Are you going to change your mind and port to Perl instead? Most languages allow you to link your own modules in, so if Java's standard RE engine isn't PCRE, you could create an interface to the PCRE library that is. But that's more work and your code won't be portable to environments without your module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your impression is incorrect. "[Perl-compatible regular expressions](http://www.pcre.org/)" are widely supported, largely by using the same engine in the background. In PHP, you get them with the `pcre_` function family. In python, they're what `re` supports. Even Mysql supports this regular expression style (with `RLIKE`), in addition to traditional SQL syntax. Languages that don't support the full perl syntax often support a compatible subset.

I can't offer a full list of languages that support it; I'm not sure the question can even be answered-- would you count gaming environments and the like if they embed regular expressions in their command language? But does it matter? Look for regexp support in the languages *you* are interested in, and if you don't find full PCRE support, chances are you'll find a good subset.

The main incompatible regexp families are SQL's `LIKE` syntax, shell-style "globs" (simpler than full regexps), and various unix tools that, for historical reasons, stick to variants of the regexp syntax: `grep` (so-called "basic" regular expressions by default), `sed`, etc. (Keep in mind that `grep` and `sed` predate not only perl, but the very culture of compatible implementations).